# Android - No drawer View found with gravity LEFT

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a `DrawerLayout` slides from right to left.

I've followed [this tutorial](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html) and found it very satisfying and clear for a `DrawerLayout` which slides from left to right.

When I change the `gravity` of `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView` to `right`, it slides from right to left, but, the burger button isn't working properly anymore, it shows `No drawer view found with gravity LEFT` when I tried touching it.

Here's the modified toggle function

```
// Initializing Drawer Layout and ActionBarToggle
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer){

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank

                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
//Added the lines below, tried solutions online but fail..
            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                if (item != null && item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
                    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                    } else {
                        drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

        };
```

So.. How to make the burger button work again?

UPDATE

Here's the XML file of the main layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".Activities.NewsfeedActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_newsfeed_wrapper"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/activity_newsfeed_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_newsfeed_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/activity_newsfeed_navigationView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here's my main class

```
public class NewsfeedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Defining Variables
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_newsfeed);

        // Initializing Toolbar and setting it as the actionbar
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.activity_newsfeed_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //Initializing NavigationView
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.activity_newsfeed_navigationView);

        //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {


                //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                if(menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
                else menuItem.setChecked(true);

                //Closing drawer on item click
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()){


                    //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                    case R.id.a:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inbox Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        ContentFragment fragment = new ContentFragment();
                        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.activity_newsfeed_frame,fragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        return true;

                    // For rest of the options we just show a toast on click

                    case R.id.b:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"b Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.c:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"c Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.d:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"d Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.e:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"e Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.f:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"f Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.g:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"g Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.h:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"h Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Somethings Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;

                }
            }
        });

        // Initializing Drawer Layout and ActionBarToggle
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer){

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank

                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }

        };

        //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        //calling sync state is necessay or else your hamburger icon wont show up
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.drawer, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                } else {
                    drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Update 02/02/2016

Tried changing drawer view to `RIGHT`.. But it's a bad idea because nothing changes. Tried moving `NavigationView` into the `LinearLayout`, it's even worse because there'll be no sliding menu..

Tried changing things in `onOptionsItemSelected`

```
case android.R.id.home:
                if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
                } else {
                    drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
                }
```

Changed `Gravity.RIGHT` to `GravityCompat.END`, "NOPE", the code says..

Comment: show me ur navigation view

Comment: There, it's in the very bottom of the layout..

Comment: chk my answer.. if you found any problem, then let me know

Answer (score 3):

try this in your navigation View

android:layout_gravity="end" in place of android:layout_gravity="right"

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"
        />
```

// Add these lines in your java activity file , it will works

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                if (mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                    mDrawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                } else {
                    mDrawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
        }
final update:
```

I change some lines in your sample project(MainActivity.java), now it is working , use this code.

do not forget to write android:layout_gravity="end" in place of android:layout_gravity="start" in your xml file.

```
package com.android4dev.navigationview;


import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        navigationView=(NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        drawerLayout=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer);


        // Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar.
        setToolbarAsActionBar();
        // Setup drawer view
        setupDrawerContent(navigationView);

        // Set the menu icon instead of the launcher icon.
        final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.starred);
        selectDrawerItem(item);

    }

    private void setToolbarAsActionBar() {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                } else {
                    drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                        //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                        if (menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
                        else menuItem.setChecked(true);

                        selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
        // Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on
        // position

        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.inbox:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inbox Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ContentFragment fragment = new ContentFragment();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                break;

            case R.id.starred:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stared Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.sent_mail:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Send Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.drafts:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Drafts Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.allmail:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All Mail Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.trash:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Trash Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.spam:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Spam Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            default:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Somethings Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

        }

        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    }

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
        return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer);
    }

}
```

Comment: There, I've modified the main activity that way.. I've followed your `onOptionsItemSelected` at the very bottom, but it still doesn't work.. Still asking for `DrawerView` with gravity `LEFT`

Comment: did you write   android:layout_gravity="end" in your navigation view.

Comment: are you using custom menu icon or default menu icon

Comment: I am using default menu icon, I simply followed the tutorial for that part.. The tutorial also doesn't use custom icon.. Probably ._.

Answer (score 0):

If you are intended your app to be RTL,

You can switch all the settings back to be equal "start" and Simply add:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

In your onCreate() function.

Please note that this will affect all the other elements in your activity as well...

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who still have this issue:
you should set this line in your NavigationView:

```
android:layout_gravity="start"
```

and this in your java:

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close){
            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                if(item != null && item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){
                    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen((Gravity.END))) {
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
                    } else {
                        drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.END);
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
```

it's worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
        val drawerLayout:DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)

        val navView:NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow
            ), drawerLayout
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        val drawertoogle = ActionBarDrawerToggle (this,drawerLayout,toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)

        drawertoogle.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled = false

        drawertoogle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener 
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END)
        }
```